# Call javascript from appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem calling ajax from appended content.

Let's show you my example (An example calling ajax request from appended content, and other call ajax request from none appended content):

https://jsfiddle.net/r7f3zo92/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new AjaxUpload("#change", {
    action: 'verifImg',
    name: 'uploadfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
      if (!(ext && /^(png|jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif)$/.test(ext))) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {

      $("#imagechange").html(response);


    }
  });


  $(document).on('click', '#test', function(ev) {

    $('body').find('#show').remove();
    var modal =
      '<div class="modal fade" id="show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="show">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">' +
      '<div class="modal-content">' +
      '<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
      '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Test</strong></h4>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-body">' +
      '<div class="row">' +

      '<div class="form-group">' +

      '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="change">Change Image</a>' +
      '<br/>' +
      '<div id="imagechange"></div>' +

      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';




    $('body').append(modal);

    $('#show').modal({
      show: true
    });
    return false;

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/1/file/51812/name/ajaxupload.3.5.js"></script>

<strong>Example with appended content:</strong>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="test">An example to test</a>

<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Direct example:</strong>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="change">Change Image</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="imagechange"></div>
</div>
```

In JSFIDDLE it's work fine, but locally no ! strange !

Can you find the problem related to this example ? Thank's

Comment: you should add that jsfiddle link as well

Comment: I added the link to JSFIDDLE.

Comment: I don't know how U structure the file, but check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116431/javascript-code-works-in-jsfiddle-and-but-not-in-the-browser). And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865241/jsfiddle-code-not-working-in-my-own-page)

Comment: can you try changing `id="test"` to `class="test"` and similar changes in JS code? Logically `id` should be unique in your HTML page.

Comment: @vijayP i changed it to class but no change same thing !

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks i made my example exactly like the solution given in your links (Added  document ready handler and tried to put the javascript links into the footer) but same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered from the `ajaxupload.js` source code, it seems like it expects one element (or id of element) available on load. On the `onload` event, it binds a whole lot of stuffs to it, using `mousemove`, etc. instead of simple `click` events. it was done for a reason (handle differences in browsers), but it means that:

- ajaxupload is only bound to one html element, which must be available on load
- it is not possible (or highly complicated) to simulate a click event on the #change button from code, since we don't know exactly what type of event and parameters it requires.

So, in my opinion, you have the following choices:

1. create a hidden input that you bind to a second `AjaxUpload`, then move it into your form every time it shows
2. change the library you use

---

To be clearer upon the first choice, here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/r7f3zo92/2/). The idea is:

- on load, you create a button `#choice2` which is hidden
- everytime you create your modal, you *move* (not clone) your button inside the modal
- upon modal close, you put back the button inside the body and hide it
- your button is ready for the next modal call.

Of course, this approach is a dirty fix and works only when you are sure only one component at a time needs the hidden button.

Comment: I tried the first solution, but no way to call the hidden button ! i tried this: `$("#change").click();` but nothing ... can you simulate an example about your opinion please ? thank's.

Comment: you cannot trigger it by code, as I said. You need to move it inside your modal with `$('#change2').appendTo('#modal-body')` for example.

Comment: This solution will be  correct if there a way to generate new button automatically when clicking on `#test` and then append it to the modal ?

Comment: As well, i tried to clone it but do not give working example too, here you can find a test: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r7f3zo92/1/)

Comment: Awesome ! problem resolved ... it's what i am looking for, thank you so much.